# Google Play Store not distributing beta application

Tags: android, google-play, beta

I have an application released to production in the google play store. I'd like to distribute an update through beta testing. I published a beta application with a greater version build number, however, any user that joins beta testing via the link https://play.google.com/apps/testing/[application.package.id] is only able to download the older production application through the store on devices that I know are targeted by the beta application.

For other applications on my account, I can distribute betas just fine when there is not yet a production release. Do the alpha/beta privileges terminate once the app goes to production?

Answer (score 1):

You can still have alpha and beta testing groups for applications in production.

The process as I am familiar:

1. test user must join a google group that has been added for alpha/beta testing for the application
2. You supply the link as in your question to user, who installs via Play Store
3. You can publish new apks to production, beta or alpha.

   1. alpha testers receive the highest code level
   2. beta testers receive the highest code level in production or beta
   3. production users receive highest code level in production

---

One user who previously had the production version installed from the play store reported they had to sign out of their play store account and sign back in to have the beta version appear.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that it should work but doesn't. Sometimes thats half the battle